# How to sort out confusion in iPhone Contact Groups?

Tags: iphone, contacts

My usage of my iPhone SE is that I never sync to the cloud because I keep private inforamtion in my Contacts.  Instead, I sync my Contacts over home Wi-Fi, and it gets synced with an Exchange Server [1].

I have never used, created, or manipulated Contact Groups on my iPhone, yet I now seem to have two versions of my Contacts.  Specifically, I have the following Contact Groups:

1. All iPhone
2. iPhone Global Address List
3. All AkrutoSync Exchange
4. AkrutoSync Exchange Global Address List

I can only enable #1 and #3.  If I try to enable #2 or #4, I am shown an empty contact list.  The disparate versions of my contacts are in #1 and #3.  There are too many contacts and details to see where the difference lie, but I know that some Contacts that I recently created on my iPhone show up in #1.  However, I consider #3 to be the main Contacts since it is synced with my laptop.

**Without using the cloud, is there any way to migrate individual contacts from #1 to #3, other than manually copying details onto a piece of paper and disabling #1, enabling #3, and typing the details in again?**

I can enable both #1 and #3, but then I get many duplicate Contacts and it's hard to tell which Contacts are from which Groups (if there is a way to determine this, I'd appreciate knowing).  The duplicates may actually be near-duplicates, and I don't consider it feasible to manually figure out where all the differences lie. I am only interested in keeping #3 and migrating Contacts that exist only in #1 to #3.

Once I've updated #3, **is there any way to "blow away" #1 Contacts and ensure that #1 is never enabled again?**

On a related note, **how can I ensure that #3 is the Group in which new contacts are created?**  If I currently create a new contact, it ends up in #1.  If I go to `Settings -> Contacts`, there is no field for designating a "default" Group.  Neither is there such a "default" field in `Settings -> Contacts -> Accounts`.

---

**NOTES**

[1] The server is actually the AkrutoSync Exchange interface to the Outlook desktop app on my laptop.

Comment: I'd be reasonably sure this is a side effect of going through two non-Apple 'translation' processes, Exchange & Akruto. You might be best approaching Akruto first about this. [I wouldn't put money on anyone regular to this stack ever having seen Akruto.]

Comment: AkrutoSync only runs on the laptop to make an Exchange Server interface available to the iPhone.  As far as the iPhone is concerned, it's just another Exchange Server.  There is no custom app running on the iPhone to connect with the server, so I'm not sure how AkrutoSync can be responsible for replicating all contacts.  Given the setup I described, is there some avenue of which I'm unaware for the contacts to be replicated?